# "Next" mobile button ignores dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing an application using React and Material-ui. The problem is: after filling a text input in a mobile device, if I click the "next" button, it tabs to the next text input, skipping any selects (dropdowns) in-between. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Probably `tabindex` is not working properly for dropdown?

Comment: It works with the tab key on desktop. Just a mobile issue